# What Postgres datatype for monetary values in a Nest.Js microservice architecture?

Tags: postgresql, rabbitmq, nestjs, microservices, prisma

I am currently working on a microservice architecture using Nest.Js and PostgreSQL, and I am facing challenges with handling monetary values. Initially, I considered using the BigInt data type to represent monetary values in the smallest currency unit (MicroUSD), where 1 million equals $1. This approach worked well when sending BigInt data from Microservice 1 to Microservice 2, as the BigInt gets serialized to a string by Microservice 1's custom serializer, and Microservice 2 then transforms it back to a BigInt using a custom decorator in its DTO (called TransformAndValidateIsBigInt, that's a mouthful).

However, I encountered issues when Microservice 2 sends back a field with a BigInt in it. Although it correctly serializes it into a BigInt when sending it back, Microservice 1 receives a string since there's no way to transform it using decorators on incoming data.

One solution I've considered is to create a ResponseDto and transform the raw data using the plainToClass function from class-transformer manually. However, this seems like a significant change and I'm not sure if it's the best approach.

I'm now wondering if I should abandon the BigInt approach altogether, despite its benefits over floating-point numbers. I'm also considering other PostgreSQL data types that might be more suitable for handling monetary values in this context.

Could anyone provide insights or recommendations on the best PostgreSQL data type to use for monetary values in a Nest.Js microservice architecture, considering these serialization and deserialization challenges?

Comment: Postgres `bigint` seems fine, as would [`numeric`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html), I would recommend to avoid [`money`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-money.html). However, I don't see what the choice of the postgres column type has to do with your serialisation issue in the communication between your microservices?